# What is good practice in choosing the return value when getting data from DB (Java)?

Tags: java

I want to get version of text from a table in DB.

I want to know 3 things:

-if it `return 0` then there is no version

-if it `return 1` or >=1 then there is a version

-if the connection to DB got problem or any kind of problem while getting data then it should `return -1`

Let read this code to see if I am doing correctly. I `return -1` at the end

```
public static int getData(String title){
   Connection myCon=null;
   PreparedStatement preparedStmt=null;
   try{
       myCon=getUnusedConnection();
       String sql="select version from table where title=?";
       preparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
       preparedStmt.setString(1, title);
       ResultSet results=preparedStmt.executeQuery();
       int version=0;
       if(results.next()){
             version=results.getInt(1);

       }
       return version; // a version existed
   }
   catch(SQLExcetion ex){
        while (ex != null) {
            System.out.println ("SQL Exception:  " +
            ex.getMessage ());
            ex = ex.getNextException ();
        }
   }catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        System.out.println("***ERROR-->" + e.toString());   
   }
   finally{
         releaseConnection (myCon);
         closeStatement (preparedStmt);
   }
   return -1; // db or java problem
}
```

Comment: Personally I'd rather throw back an exception in the event of a problem and return a boolean to indicate success/failure

Comment: @ fge, if return true or false then how i can get the version, version could be 1 , 2 , 3 ....

Comment: So now you want the version? This isn't what your original question is asking

Comment: Just a feedback more on the code rather than the question, is 'version' nullable in your table? If so, looks like your code will not return a '0' value. Because if there is no results fetched it will return '-1' since flow will reach the end.

Comment: @ Rebecca, it like 1 method that check 3 things so the name of method should be changed then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning an error code is a terribly outdated practice. Use exception objects to specify not only the kind of error, but also any kind of data that needs to accompany your errors. The pattern is really quite simple: return what the output of your function ought to be and throw exceptions when encountering errors. If done properly you never have to interpret a return value.

It is good practice to wrap exceptions in other exceptions, so as to make it easy on callers of your methods to handle those exception. So this would be a good start:

```
// your wrapper
class DbException extends Exception {
    public DbException(string msg, Throwable rootCause) {
        super(msg, rootCause);
    }
}

public static int getVersion(String title) throws DbException {
    try {   
        // get version
         ....
        //
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new DbException("Problem getting version", SqlException ex);    
    }
    return version;
}
```

Since now the output of your method is clear I've renamed `getData` to `getVersion`, because that is always what is gotten.

Your wrapper exception could also be of a more abstract kind that just DbException (like TurnWrapper) and you may also choose to use a RuntimeException instead of a checked exception if you'd prefer not to have each caller explicitly handle your exceptions (I usually do).

That being said it stands to reason if not having a version is an error or not. If your codebase is not meant to encounter problems resolving versions it is an error and you ought to throw an exception. Judging by the signature of your method though not being able to resolve a version seems quite possible. String title may be anything, so you're leaving a lot of room for not being able to resolve a version.

There are a few options now:

1) instead of return int you can return Integer and return null when no version could be resolved. The problem with this approach is that you leave room for causing a NullPointerException. I would not advise this unless you are working with an IDE that can help you catch these kind of problems. [Eclipse for example has an excellent @Nullable annoation that can prevent NPE at comile time](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_annotations.htm).  Your method signature would become

```
public @Nullable Integer getVersion(String title) throws DbException
```

I'd prefer this signature if you have @Nullable compile time checking, because this way your calling code is forced to check for null pointers and the methods signature is self explanatory .

2) Return an int like you've suggested, but a negative value means no version could be gotten. This prevent NPE, but still leaves room for errors. This is simple enough. Your siguanture would become:

```
/**
 * @return version or -1 if no version could be resolved
 */
public int getVersion(String title) throws DbException
```

Comment: thank you very much, i think this is what i need. This is the correct way to do. I learned in school only without any professional experience so they taught me that way

Comment: It's C style programming in the 21st century. Your school should have its license to teach revoked :)

Answer (score 0):

if a problem is an exceptional case, you should prefer an exception. If you insist on return codes, I recommend using an `enum` with mnemonic entries, e.g.

```
public enum ReturnValues {
    NO_VERSION(0), VERSION_FOUND(1), ERROR(-1);

    private final int code;

    private ReturnValues(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }
}
```

Comment: "if a problem is an exceptional case, you should prefer an exception." <-- If I could upvote this multiple times, I would.

Comment: u didn't state clearly how to do it in context of getting Data Java code. U just create a class enum

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get rid of the checked SqlException, then :

```
throw new IllegalStateException("Database connection failure",originalSqlException);
```

If there is no version:

```
return null;  // do not fear nothing. In this case it is truly nothing.
```

Indicate in the javadoc that the method will return null if no version was found, and that it may throw an IllegalStateException if there was a database problem.

Do not catch *all* types of exceptions, and do not log anything.

There is no need of logging the error at this point, just leave it to the caller to handle the exception.

```
catch( SQLException ex ){
    throw new IllegalStateException("Database connection failure",ex);
    }
}
finally {
    //etc...
```

Comment: but my real world project is very complecated, it has Inter.parseInt.... then should i catch Exception as well?

Comment: You can catch the ParseException too. If you want to indicate to a user that there is a specific problem with the version number, create an application specific exception that says that the version number is malformed. (Perhaps a generic application error with a code that can be used to present a translated error text.) Catch that exception in an appropriate place (as "high" as possible) and show a proper error message.